# How to redirect parked domain to main domain but still show the parked domain in address bar

Tags: redirects, subdomain

I have a main hosting registered with the domain `example.com`. The hosting allows me to park another domain. I want that any person that access to `example2.com` be redirected to `sub.example.com`. In this way:

```
the user access to:               example2.com/something/a.html
The user sees the content of:     sub.example.com/something/a.html
And the browser displays:         example2.com/something/a.html
```

I tried to do a CNAME from `example2.com` to `sub.example.com` but the pages go to `example.com`. I think that is because the domain is parked at that hosting.

When I get that done, how I ensure that Google displays `example2.com` and not the other subdomain?

Comment: There's also a way with `.htaccess`, which I can't remember off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into doing a "frame redirect".   It is also sometimes called "web forwarding" or "masked redirect".   In that case the redirect server issues content like this:

```
<html>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
<frame src="http://www.example.com/my-page.html" noresize frameborder="0">
</frameset>
</html>
```

This causes the browser to show the contents of your main site, but the URL will show the redirect domain.

This type of redirect is not ideal:

- The URL doesn't change as the user browses around the site
- It breaks bookmarking functionality

The other option is to fully duplicate the content and fully host two different domains that have all the same pages on them.

Comment: Or with a webhosting with multidomain funcionalities. (: Thanks!